# Android Device Chooser not showing my device but adb and Eclipse do

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, adb, adt

I am trying to run my android app in an attached device (Sony Ericson Xperia X10). The device is recognized by adb

```
[fonoro@localhost platform-tools]$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
CB511LNF7V  device
```

Eclipse's "Devices" view, lists my device correctly as "sony_ericsson-x10i-CB511LNF7V". I am even able to take screen shoots of the device from Eclipse. However, for some reason it does not appear AT ALL on the Android Device Chooser. I have tried the usual (restart adb, set the device to debugging mode, etc.) but this specific problem is not addressed elsewhere.

I am using Fedora 18 / Eclipse 4.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be your device's API level is less than what your application needs

Comment: Min. required API level is 9. The phone's API is 10. Tried with API level 7 just in case with the same results.

Comment: You were right! I checked everything again and found that although the target API was 2.1, the minSdkVersion attribute in the Manifest was expecting a level 17 API. Changed it to "7" and solved the problem. Thank you.